# How to make the surface look smooth, i have used the modifiers

Tags: modeling, rendering, modifiers

I've modeled a "yakult" bottle with a mesh cylinder, and have used a modifier tool (Subdivision Surface and Smooth) to make it look soft. I'm happy with the results on a solid preview, but when I render, It looks like a line which is stripped or surface lines appears.
the question is, how can I make the modeling look solid and smooth on render preview? What should I do?

[image: preview]

[image: preview]

Comment: for future reference please use the built in image upload tools. There are too many instances where other sites drop the images. Then the posts here are broken.

Answer (score 2):

I have taken a sphere and added Subdivision Surface Modifier to it with the view 2 and Render 0

[image]

As you can see the sphere look smooth. But when i hit render i get this render

[image]

Flat or un-smooth sphere

Reason is the setting in the subdivision instead of Render value 0 make the same value of 2

And you will see the same result seen in the 3d solid view.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it may be a mesh display setting. With your object selected, go to the right hand tools menu, and under shading, select *Smooth* [image]

Alternatively again with the object selected, press <kbd>Space</kbd>, search for "shade smooth" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone :), very helpful answer...hope you have a great day,
finaly my problem is solved, thats really what you say, just change the render value, make it same with view value...KABOOM!!

Thanks in advance :)

[image]